# Best practice for massive postgres tables

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, database-partitioning

I have a table with 3 fields (username, target_value, score) generated externally by a full cross of username's (~400,000) and target_value's (~4000) and a calculated score, leading to a total row count of ~1.6 billion.

All my query's on this table will be in the format of

```
SELECT *
FROM _table
WHERE target_values IN (123, 456)
```

My initial version of this included a BTREE index on target_values but i ended up spending 45 minutes on a BITMAP HEAP SCAN of the index.
I've also been looking at BRIN indexes, partitions and table clustering but as it takes hours to apply each approach to the table i cant exactly brute force each option and test for performance.

What are some recommendations for dealing with a single massive table with very 'blocky' data in Postgres 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the table is a cross join of two data sets, why don't you store the individual tables and calculate the join as you need it? Databases are good at that.

From your description I would expect a performance gain if you ran `CLUSTER` on the table to physically rewrite it in index order. Then you would have to access way fewer table blocks.

Unfortunately `CLUSTER` will take long, makes the table unavailable and has to be repeated regularly.

An alternative that may be better is to partition the table by `target_value`. 4000 partitions are a bit much, so maybe use list partitioning to bundle several together into one partition.

This will allow your queries to perform fast sequential scans on only a few partitions. It will also make autovacuum's job easier.

The bottom line, however, is that if you select a lot of rows from a table, it will always take a long time.

Comment: sadly the score generation is done externally by Spark with a ML model, so i cant store and calculate on the fly.

Comment: BTW, do you have a recommend max for the number of partitioning? 50? 100? 500?

Comment: The higher the PostgreSQL version, the more partitions can be handled efficiently. With v12 (released yesterday) you may be able to handle 4000 partitions. You should run some tests. The problem with many partitions is that planning time might increase a lot.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Are they 4000 partitions per table or is it per database?

Comment: Per table. But the point where it starts to hurt depends on how much planning time is acceptable for you.